# Most of the audience is/are

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, collective-nouns

Should I use *are* or *is* in the following sentence?

> Most of the audience **is/are** sleeping.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58692/is-audience-singular-or-plural

Comment: @VarunKN This question is primarily about ***most***, not *audience*.

Answer (score 1):

When expressed as a group, *audience* is singular:

> Do not expect massive page views at 3 AM when your target audience is sleeping.

When expressed as individuals within a whole, *audience* is plural:

> You can tell a movie is poor when many in the audience are sleeping.

Comment: In *many in the audience are sleeping*, the word *audience* is not the head of the noun phrase functioning as subject.

Comment: The question does not ask about *audience* but about ***most** of the audience*.

Answer (score 1):

> Most of the audience is/are sleeping.

"Of the audience" is a prepositional phrase and can essentially be struck from the sentence to look at the rest of the structure. So look at:

> Most <strike>of the audience</strike> is/are sleeping.

Here it it obvious that the phrase should be "Most are..."

Comment: How do you explain the difference between *most of the apples are* and *most of the water is* without paying attention to the preposition phrase?

Comment: @snailboat : LOL - Well it seemed clear a few hours ago... Nice counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. It actually depends if you want to use *audience* as singular or plural.

We have to look at two different things here: first, we need to identify the subject of the sentence; second, we need to determine whether the collective noun is singular or plural.

---

**Determining the subject of the sentence.**

> Most of the audience is/are sleeping.

The subject in your sentence is *Most*, not *audience*. *Audience* is the object.

*Most* is a determiner and an indefinite pronoun. It can be singular or plural based on the object of the preposition that follows. If the noun after *of* is singular, use a singular verb; if it is plural, use a plural verb.

---

**Is the collective noun singular or plural?**

As [@lurker](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/26773/lurker) already stated in [his/her answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/77800/20213):

> When expressed as a group, *audience* is singular.  
>   When expressed as individuals within a whole, *audience* is plural

*Audience* is a collective noun; it can be singular or plural depending on the author's intent.

---

**Note:** Americans tend to treat collective nouns as single units. In British usage, it's the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Str: Most/ Most of /more + Sub(plu)

1. Most of the visitors were American
2. More people came to the concert than expected

Comment: Your answer avoids the question, the noun phrase is "Most of the audience" NOT "Most of the visitors”. And sentence 2 bears no relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers are discussing whether the word 'audience' is singular or plural, and some are suggesting it could be both. This is false. From a purely grammatical standpoint, 'audience' is a *collective* noun, and is singular. When you are referring to one audience, whether that audience consists of just one person or many, you use the singular collective term 'audience'. The plural of 'audience' is '*audiences*'.

However, in your example, you are referring to *individuals* in that group. The word 'most' can only be used when something can be counted, and in this case is referring to the numerical majority of the individuals making up the audience. So, in this case, and other similar cases, you are fine to use 'are'.